# Showing two matrix blocks are similar

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, block-matrices, similar-matrices

Let $A \in M_n$ and $B,C \in M_m$. Prove that if

$$H= \begin{bmatrix}
    A&0  \\
    0 & B
  \end{bmatrix}$$

is similar to

$$K = \begin{bmatrix}
    A&0  \\
    0 & C
  \end{bmatrix}$$

then $B$ is similar to $C$.

---

I am not sure how I would do this I know that if $H$ is similar to $K$ then for some non-singular matrix $S$ then $S^{-1} H S=K$.

Comment: I'd write $A,B,C$ and $S$ explicitly. A proper submatrix of $S$ to show that $B$ and $C$ are similar should become apparent.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using Jordan form: there exists matrices $P,Q,R$ such that $P^{-1}AP = J_A$, $Q^{-1}BQ = J_B$, and $RCR^{-1}  = J_C$ are all in Jordan normal form.

We then note that
$$
\pmatrix{P\\&Q}^{-1}\pmatrix{A\\&B}  \pmatrix{P\\&Q} = \pmatrix{J_A\\& J_B}\\
\pmatrix{P\\&R}^{-1}\pmatrix{A\\&C}  \pmatrix{P\\&R} = \pmatrix{J_A\\& J_C}
$$
By the uniqueness of Jordan form (up to permutations of blocks), the two matrices on the right can only be similar if $J_B$ is similar to $J_C$, which is to say that $B$ is similar to $C$ as desired.

Answer (score 3):

Since $H$ and $K$ are similar, $B$ and $C$ have same set of distinct eigenvalues. Also $B$ and $C$ have same generalized eigenspaces (same number of independent vectors) for distinct eigenvalues, i.e.
$$
\operatorname{Rank}(\lambda_iI-B)^n=\operatorname{Rank}(\lambda_iI-C)^n
$$
where $\lambda_i$ are distinct eigenvalues of $B$ and $C$. Hence $B$ and $C$ are similar.

Comment: is the minimum polynomial the same thing as the charecteritstic polynoial.

Comment: It is **not** true that matrices with the same minimal polynomial are necessarily similar

Comment: That true it only say if they are similar they have the minimal polynomial but how would I solve this

Comment: Instead of minimal polynomials, we could use either Jordan form or Frobenius normal form. Do you know what either of those are?

Comment: Why was this accepted?

Comment: Actually, as the comment below your question indicates, theres another approach

Comment: I know the jordan form

Comment: @User1006 it's still wrong. Matrices can have the same minimal polynomials, the same eigenvalues up to multiplicity, the same eigenspaces, and could still fail to be similar. I don't understand why you decided to use anything other than Jordan form in this context.

Comment: @User1006 That isn't sufficient.  There's is no way to answer this question using eigenvalues/eigenspaces alone, even if you also use the minimal polynomial.

Comment: So maybe I am supposed to use jordan form because I covered it in class maybe but I am not sure how to apply it here

Comment: @User1006 That's an interesting conjecture you have.  I'll post a question about it.  Feel free to try to prove it, and I'll try to construct a counterexample.  In the mean time, I am fairly confident that you are wrong.

Comment: @User1006 [here's the question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2012475/are-eigenspaces-and-minimal-polynomials-sufficient-for-similarity)

Comment: @User1006 I've posted the question and my answer in the link above, and so I am quite confident that you are wrong. I encourage you to find the flaw in my argument, if there is one.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom, it should be $Rank(\lambda_iI-B)^n=Rank(\lambda_iI-C)^n$. So both have same number of independent eigenvectors

Comment: @User1006 I agree that with the $n$ there (for arbitrary integers $n$), having that is enough; it is well known that these values can be used to "encode" the Jordan form.  I don't know what you're saying about "independent eigenvectors", though.

Comment: (The sequence of these values is known as the "Weyr characteristic")

Comment: *"$B$ and $C$ have same number of independent vectors for eigenspace of distinct eigenvalues"* is not a correct interpretation of the statement
$$
Rank(\lambda_iI-B)^n=Rank(\lambda_iI-C)^n \quad n=1,2,3,\dots
$$ In particular, we would need to say something about *generalized* eigenspaces in order to capture what's going on.

Comment: Also, now that you've effectively proven that $B$ and $C$ have the same Jordan form, your earlier statement about minimal polynomials is redundant.